# VBA Worksheets not looping after adding Worksheet.name

Tags: vba, loops

I have a macro that runs fine on the first worksheet but crashes when it tried to go to the next worksheet. I get a Run-time Error 1004 Application-defined or objecct-defined error.

My code returned the values of the cell before and it looped fine. I changed the code because there were blank cells in my source data and when it copy and paste to my master Sheet it left a blank cell offsetting my data.

It stopped looping after i change the macro to pull Cell address instead of values.

My code is

```
Sub Test()

Dim imaxrow As Double
Dim i As Double
Dim wscount As Double

wscount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


For i = 2 To wscount
    'Rows of data to be extracted
    imaxrow = 22 'Max rows
    'Use to offset columns to next dataset
        For Each e In Array(0, 11)
        'Starting row to copy data
        For irow = 10 To imaxrow
            If Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 21 + e).Value = "" Then
                'Nothing in this cell.
                'Do nothing.
                Else
                ' Copy Cell data to mastersheet


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 21 + e).Address


                 Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 22 + e).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 23 + e).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 24 + e).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 4).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(irow, 3).Address



                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(5, 1).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(6, 21 + e).Address


                Worksheets("macro test sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "=" & Worksheets(i).Name & "!" & Worksheets(i).Cells(7, 21 + e).Address

            End If
        Next irow
        Next e
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you describe occurs when you do not properly reference a worksheet name, in this case, i think it is a sheet name that may contain spaces.  Try enclosing the worksheet name with a single quote or double quote:

`... "='" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!"  ...`

Comment: IT WORKED, thank you so much, i was staring at this for an hour.